# Understanding javap output

Tags: java, class, javap

I have a very simple class:

```
package MyDev;

public class Point3D  {

   public Point3D(){x = 0; y = 0;z = 0;}

   public float x, y, z;
   public Point3D( float X, float Y, float Z ) 
   {
      x = X;  y = Y;  z = Z;
   }
}
```

When I run `javap -c` on this class, that is what I get:

```
C:\Projects\Development\MyJava\bin\MyDev>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javap" -c Point3D.class
Compiled from "Point3D.java"
public class MyDev.Point3D {
  public float x;

  public float y;

  public float z;

  public MyDev.Point3D();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #12                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: fconst_0
       6: putfield      #14                 // Field x:F
       9: aload_0
      10: fconst_0
      11: putfield      #16                 // Field y:F
      14: aload_0
      15: fconst_0
      16: putfield      #18                 // Field z:F
      19: return

  public MyDev.Point3D(float, float, float);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #12                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: fload_1
       6: putfield      #14                 // Field x:F
       9: aload_0
      10: fload_2
      11: putfield      #16                 // Field y:F
      14: aload_0
      15: fload_3
      16: putfield      #18                 // Field z:F
      19: return
}
```

Why? **Why the second constructor has a signature ()V too, instead of (FFF)V ?**
For the life of me I cannot understand that!

Comment: There is no `(float,float,float)` constructor on Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the call to the constructor of `Object`. The call to the superclass constructor is always the first thing that happens in a constructor.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, should have run it with -c -s to make things clearer. Answer accepted and upvoted.